# How to turn off bracketed paste mode?

Tags: terminal-emacs, copy-paste

I saw that bracketed paste mode is automatically enabled in Emacs 25.1 running in a terminal.

But I want to disable this mode. Because this mode adds text like `200~ 201~` to pasted text, bracketed paste mode annoys me.

I have googled But there is no information about disabling bracketed paste mode in emacs.

My development environment is macOS Sierra, and Emacs 25.1.
How can I turn off bracketed paste mode?

I frequently copy text from web browser, then paste it into Emacs running in terminal. But something text is added for copied text, e.g. `200~hello, world201~`.
So these annoying characters reduce my productivity because I have to delete them after pasting text. I want to remove these characters.

Comment: Good question. I see nothing in the manual about it, and `C-h n` (NEWS) says only this: "*Bracketed paste mode is disabled by default, so Emacs automatically enables it at startup if the terminal supports it.*" I'm not sure how you find out more about it. I filed Emacs bug #[24995](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24995) to get some more doc about it.

Comment: Btw: what's your terminal configuration, wnd what's your actual problem? Bracketed pasted mode should "just work"; there should be little reason to disable it.

Comment: IOW: if Emacs thinks your terminal supports it, but your terminal actually doesn't , then there's a bug in the terminal database; if your terminal does support it, but Emacs prints unwanted characters, then there's a bug in Emacs.  In all cases, there's a bug that needs to be fixed; switching bracketed paste mode off would just hide it.

Comment: @Clément I frequently copy text from web browser, then paste it into emacs running in terminal. But something text is added for copied text. `ex) 200~hello, world201~`

Comment: So these annoying text reduce my productivity Becuase I have to delete these annoying text after pasting text. I want to remove these text

Comment: Right. So you don't actually want to disable bracketed paste mode at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My crystal ball said you should remove

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'previous-multiframe-window)
```

from your `~/.emacs`.  You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and ask for `global-set-key` to complain when the key sequence conflicts with something in `input-decode-map` (as is the case here, because the byte sequence `ESC [` (which corresponds to the `M-[` event) is used by text terminal as a prefix for encoding all kinds of special events).

Comment: Thank you! That thing was driving my crazy since upgrading to 25.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to switch it off, as far as I can tell. You'd need a way to get Emacs to write `printf "\e[?2004l"` to stdout (as [discussed here](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste)) to disable the feature.

This was introduced in Emacs 25.1, as discussed in [bug #24995](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24995).

The problem is that you have a keybinding that starts `M-[` in your configuration. If you remove that keybinding, Emacs should interpret the bracketed paste characters correctly. It looks like Emacs interprets some of the bracketed paste characters as commands, leading to the `200~hello, world201~` mess.

You may be able to work around the problem by switching to `fundamental-mode` before pasting, which tends to have fewer keybindings.